# reading multiple files containing multiple csv's

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have 2 years daily sales data which is divided into monthly files.

I have multiple folders, each  folder contains multiple csv.
I want to read it in Python using pandas.

I have tried for 1 folder

```
    path =r'C:\DRO\DCL_rawdata_files' # use your path
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
    list_.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(list_)
```

but as mentioned This for 1 folder, like wise I have run the same chunk of code 100 times, for 100 folders.

Is their some way to to use reduce it running again and again for each folder.?

Comment: Your issue is probably because the file is still compressed. In this instance I would probably try and curate your data before importing it into pandas.

Comment: Could you provide full traceback and minimal data that reproduces your issue?

Comment: @Alex I cannot they are hundreds of them, also the reason to read into python is to clean it.

Comment: @Shubham. hence "minimal data".  Unzip a file, and create a zip with a couple edited CSV files with a couple lines of data.  Fake the data if it is something you don't want to share.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a mock-up of what you have described, the folder structure is as follows:

```
/test/so/
  1/
    a.csv
    b.csv
  2/
    c.csv
    d.csv
  3/
    e.csv
    f.csv
```

The code below:

- Creates a [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) of your input directory
- Checks this directory and it's sub-directories for files with the suffix `.csv`
- Iterates over the list of `.csv` files opening them as pd.DataFrame
- This list of DataFrames is then concatenated into a single DataFrame

The limitation of this method is that it expects all of your files to be the same format.

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('/test/so/')

files = []
file_extensions = ['.csv']
for file_or_directory in p.iterdir():
    if file_or_directory.is_file() and ''.join(file_or_directory.suffixes).lower() in file_extensions:
        files.append(file_or_directory)
    elif file_or_directory.is_dir():
        files.extend([x for x in file_or_directory.iterdir() if ''.join(x.suffixes).lower() in file_extensions])
print(files)
[PosixPath('/test/so/1/a.csv'), PosixPath('/test/so/1/b.csv'),
 PosixPath('/test/so/2/c.csv'), PosixPath('/test/so/2/d.csv'),
 PosixPath('/test/so/3/e.csv'), PosixPath('/test/so/3/f.csv')]

df_list = []
for f in files:
    try:
        df_list.append(pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=f))
    except pd.errors.ParserError as e:
        raise pd.errors.ParserError('Input file probably not expected format')
df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
    0   1   2   3
0   a   b   c   d
1   e   f   g   h
2   i   j   k   l
3   m   n   o   p
4   q   r   s   t
5   u   v   w   x
```